# Sum field with condition

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table test

```
id order hour
```

I have two situations :

> First case : nothing to do

```
id order hour
1  1     20
2  1     40
3  1     50
```

Second case :

```
id order hour
1  1     20
1  2     50
1  3     70
2  1     40
2  2     10
2  3     20
2  4     90
3  1     50
```

I need to get 
   id hour

```
1 120 //hour total=50+70 for id=1 when order >1 
2  120//hour total for=10+20+90 id=2 when order >1
3  50  // nothing to do because I have one row for id=3
```

How can I do something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.  The SUM for id=3 will be 50, so you can still use SUM in that case.

```
SELECT id, SUM(hour) AS HourTotal 
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE [order] > 1 OR 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND [order] > 1) 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I did not understand the down vote.  The question asks for 3 rows with totals as the answer, being that id=3's total is 50.

Comment: Downvoted because the sum is wrong in the case for id 1 and 2 - it's too high. The rows with order > 1 should not be included, except if it's a single row (the id 3 case).

Answer (score 0):

this below code is working . i have tested . please try

```
select ID,SUM(HourTotal)  as hourtotal from (
    select id,HourTotal,row_num
    from (SELECT id, hour_n AS HourTotal ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id ) row_num
    FROM id )a
    where a.id!=a.row_num)b
    group by id
```

Comment: He meant to edit your own answer (I'm saying this because @AdiT tried to edit wdosanjos answer)

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code.it is working

```
select ID,SUM(HourTotal)  as hourtotal from (
        select id,HourTotal,row_num
        from (SELECT id, hour_n AS HourTotal ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id ) row_num
        FROM id )a
        where a.id!=a.row_num)b
        group by id
```